# How to disable "Quick Access" on Windows 10 Home?

Tags: windows-10, tasks

On a laptop with Windows 10 Home I have tried to disable `Quick Access` following [these steps](http://www.windowscentral.com/how-remove-quick-access-file-explorer-windows-10). However, after rebooting the laptop, `Quick Access` was still causing issues and appeared in the list of Processes in the Task Manager. I verified that the Attribute value, as described, still was on the new value of a0600000.

What else can I try?

The main issues I have are:

1. `Quick Access` causes a high CPU load
2. `Quick Access` causes a problem on the screen; a third of the screen on the right side gets just black and you have to force shutdown the `Quick Access` task in order to see the full screen again.

`Quick Access` is a task:

[image]

Comment: What Quick Access process? I haven’t ever seen this.

Comment: Please see the link I have posted. It is connected to the Windows Explorer...

Comment: It is not “connected” to Explorer, it *is* Explorer. It *cannot* appear as a process. I also don’t see how it could cause high CPU usage, it’s just a list of files and folders.

Comment: I just added a screenshot which shows that `Quick Access` is something running on the laptop

Comment: Thanks for the Screenshot. This is not a Windows process. Please bring up the context menu on this entry and select “Go to details”. In the Details view, make sure both the “Command line” and “Image path name” columns are activated. Then check where the `.exe` in question is located and report back.

Comment: The command line is `"C:\Program Files\Acer\Acer Quick Access\QuickAccess.exe" -hide` and the image path name points to the same executable.

Maybe this is something Acer specific?

Comment: If its acer specific I suggest you get rid of the bloatware. That kinda stuff only slows down your computer.

Comment: @Dylan: Yes, now that I know it's from Acer and not from Windows itself...